# ImageMagick convert works in commandline, but not via PHP exec()

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, centos

I am using PHP's `exec()` to convert an image using ImagicMagick's `convert`. This is being run on a CentOS server.

```
exec(convert http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png.jpg 
    -resize 640 /home/mysite/public_html/public/img/posts/original/1414_301a4.jpg);
```

Using `exec()` does not cause the new image to appear in the destination folder. However if I were to run the same command in the shell, it works perfectly!

I believe this is a PATH problem. If so, how can I check the path that PHP is using, and how can I set the correct path in PHP?

Comment: It is likely that your destination folder is not writable by whatever runs your php. Likely some kind of www user.

Comment: Is `convert` in the path of whatever shell PHP will be firing up to run the command? A simple `echo $PATH` exec would tell you.

Comment: Oops I left out the quotes here, its definitely there in the actual code that I used. What should the folder permission of the directory be? 777? Its currently 755. Will changing the owner/group of the folder help, or will that mess things up?

Comment: I did a `chmod 777` on the folder I'm getting Imagemagick to write to, and it works now with `exec()`.

Comment: I have the same problem but with liferay. Works in terminal but not in with liferay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** you should try with an input file that does *indeed* exist and is retrievable:

```
wget http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png.jpg

  --2012-08-21 20:55:24--  http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png.jpg
  Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 173.194.35.179, 173.194.35.177, 173.194.35.178, ...
  Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|173.194.35.179|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
  2012-08-21 20:55:24 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

**Then,** to see which `convert` your PHP uses:

```
exec(which convert 2>/tmp/whichconvert.2 1>whichconvert.1)
```

and

```
cat /tmp/whichconvert.{1,2}
```

**Last,** also try with the full path to `convert`:

```
exec(/usr/local/full/path/to/convert logo: 
-resize 640 /home/mysite/public_html/public/img/posts/original/1414_301a4.jpg);
```

and then

```
identify /home/mysite/public_html/public/img/posts/original/1414_301a4.jpg
```

---

#### Update:

The file that you meant to retrieve was probably not `logo3w.png.jpg`, but `logo3w.png`:

```
  wget http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
  --2012-08-21 21:04:22--  http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
  Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 173.194.35.180, 173.194.35.177, 173.194.35.179, ...
  Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|173.194.35.180|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
  Length: 7007 (6.8K) [image/png]
  Saving to: ‘logo3w.png’
  
  100%[=====================================================>] 7,007       --.-K/s   in 0.02s   
  
  2012-08-21 21:04:22 (451 KB/s) - ‘logo3w.png’ saved [7007/7007]
```

**Also,** in case it works for local files only (not remote http-URIs) you may need to check if the *http delegate* used by `convert` is indeed installed on your system:

```
convert -list delegate | grep http
      https =>          "/opt/local/bin/curl" -s -k -o "%o" "https:%M"
```

**Plus,** check if the user account your PHP runs under does indeed have the right to write to the target directory:

```
exec(touch /home/mysite/public_html/public/img/posts/original/touchtest);
```

and then

```
ls -l  /home/mysite/public_html/public/img/posts/original/touchtest
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function execute($command)
{
    # remove newlines and convert single quotes to double to prevent errors
    $command = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array('', '"'), $command);
    # replace multiple spaces with one
    $command = preg_replace('#(\s){2,}#is', ' ', $command);
    # escape shell metacharacters
    $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
    # execute convert program
    return shell_exec($command); // or whatever you like
}
```

Comment: Oh! Finally someone who consider escaping a required practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was providing the full path to the `ImageMagick` binary. Instead of `convert`, use `/path/to/convert`.

```
$command = $this->imageMagickFullBinaryPath . ' -resize ' . $dimensions . 
           ' ' . $imageFileToResize . ' ' . $resultingThumbnail; 
exec($command, $output);
```