# Convert ImageMagick Command to PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have tried to change the following command(s) to PHP but I don´t know
how I can achieve this.
Can anyone make a suggestion?

```
convert demo.jpg remove_background.jpg \
      -compose difference -composite -separate \
      -evaluate-sequence max -auto-level -negate \
      match_alpha.png

convert -brightness-contrast 10x10 match_alpha.png output.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution to exec the commands in PHP:

```
function execute($command)
    {
        # remove newlines and convert single quotes to double to prevent errors
        $command = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array('', '"'), $command);
        # replace multiple spaces with one
        $command = preg_replace('#(\s){2,}#is', ' ', $command);
        # escape shell metacharacters
        $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
        # execute convert program
        return shell_exec($command); // or whatever you like
    }
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061367/1648370